# Skipping Current Iteration of For Loop if Condition is False

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, if-statement, iterator, conditional-statements

I've got a large subroutine (1958 lines) to calculate some prices and figures based on a complex decision tree.

The figures will be in one of multiple tables, so to check if there is an applicable set of data to use, I've got the following `If statement`

```
If dDt.Rows.Count = 0 And cDt.Rows.Count = 0 And p1Dt.Rows.Count = 0 And p2Dt.Rows.Count = 0 And p3Dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
   If SysAQ = False Then
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    MessageBox.Show("There are no rates in the system for " & cmbSupplier.Text & "/" & ugr.Cells("Product_Code").Value & "/" & cmbCustCode.Text & " for todays " & _
           "date. Please add one and try again.", "No Rate Exists", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    ugr.Cells("DSC_Code").Value = ""
    ugr.Cells("DSC_Rate").Value = 0
    ugr.Cells("DSC_Value").Value = 0
    ugr.Cells("DSC_VAT").Value = 0

    Exit Sub
  ElseIf suppAQ = False Then
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    MessageBox.Show("There are no rates in the system for " & cmbSupplier.Text & "/" & ugr.Cells("Product_Code").Value & "/" & cmbCustCode.Text & " for todays " & _
               "date. Please add one and try again.", "No Rate Exists", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

      ugr.Cells("DSC_Code").Value = ""
      ugr.Cells("DSC_Rate").Value = 0
      ugr.Cells("DSC_Value").Value = 0
      ugr.Cells("DSC_VAT").Value = 0

      Exit Sub
  ElseIf aDt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
      Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
      MessageBox.Show("There are no rates in the system for " & cmbSupplier.Text & "/" & ugr.Cells("Product_Code").Value & "/" & cmbCustCode.Text & " for todays " & _
        "date. Please add one and try again.", "No Rate Exists", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

       ugr.Cells("DSC_Code").Value = ""
       ugr.Cells("DSC_Rate").Value = 0
       ugr.Cells("DSC_Value").Value = 0
       ugr.Cells("DSC_VAT").Value = 0

       Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

This block of code is within a `For Loop`, `For Each ugr As UltraGridRow in ugLines.Rows`

This means it's checking if there is a price for the product on the line, and if not, alerts the user and exits the subroutine.

This subroutine is called on `ugLines.AfterRowInsert`, (Once a product has been added), as well as before saving the full data.

It works fine for the latter scenario, as whenever it detects a line with no price, it will error and not save. However, if a product has been added with no price, then the user adds another product, it will never add the price in or tell the user the new line is missing a price as the first one always fails.

What I'm wondering, is if there is another way to set this out? Instead of having `Exit Sub`, can I change it to skip the rest of the code and jump straight to the next iteration? I've looked at using `Continue` and `Continue For`, but that seems to be only applicable if checking the opposite, to check where each product does have a price in at least one of the tables, making the `If Statement` more complex - Is there another way around this?

Comment: Maybe a Exit For can help you?

Comment: The code in each branch is the same so you obviously need only one `If` without `Else`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I see what you mean, I could just `OrElse` instead, right?

Comment: @muffi Would that not skip all rows, rather than just the current iteration?

Comment: @Harambe: yes, exactly. Or evaulate this condition before the `If` and assign it to a `Boolean` with a meaningful name. That's easier to read and to debug. You could even use a custom method to determine this boolean if it's getting too complex

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's not the issue that I'm having, though. Whilst that tidies up the code a little, what I'm trying to achieve is that if I want to check 3 rows and populate the prices, it's currently exiting if the first row has no price, whereas I want it to go to the next iteration, rather than exit the subroutine.

Comment: Yes, then use: `If noRatesInSystem Then Continue For`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, just changing the code in your question to the following:

```
Dim noRatesInSystem As Boolean = False
If dDt.Rows.Count = 0 And cDt.Rows.Count = 0 And p1Dt.Rows.Count = 0 And p2Dt.Rows.Count = 0 And p3Dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
  If SysAQ = False OrElse suppAQ = False OrElse aDt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
     Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
     MessageBox.Show("There are no rates in the system for " & cmbSupplier.Text & "/" & ugr.Cells("Product_Code").Value & "/" & cmbCustCode.Text & " for todays " & _
         "date. Please add one and try again.", "No Rate Exists", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
          ugr.Cells("DSC_Code").Value = ""
          ugr.Cells("DSC_Rate").Value = 0
          ugr.Cells("DSC_Value").Value = 0
          ugr.Cells("DSC_VAT").Value = 0

          noRatesInSystem = True
   End If
End If

If noRatesInSystem = True Then Continue For
```

This will A) Tidy up the `If Statement`, B) Continue the loop if a price is found and C) Skip the iteration (Jump to `Next`) if there are no prices found.

Comment: I see that you are aware of `OrElse` - `AndAlso` is useful too. Also, there is no point in using the `= True` in `If <booleanVariable> = True...`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yeah I've used `AndAlso` a lot too in my programs, it's a helpful little operator to keep things maintainable and easier to debug imo. I wasn't aware that I didn't need the `= True` though when dealing with booleans! I've always just assumed I've needed it tbh.